# How can I permanently increase max_input_vars? The php.ini approach periodically gets overridden

Tags: php, debian, vps, plesk

I manage a VPS, where I would like to increase the `max_input_vars` for one of the WordPress sites that is hosted on the VPS.  To do this, I headed over to `/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/` and entered the following into the enclosed `php.ini` file:

`max_input_vars =4000`

Whilst this worked, the file gets overridden periodically and thus I lose my modification.

Is there an alternative way to achieve this modification, without the worry of the `php.ini` being automatically overridden?

I have tried the following but all have resulted in the website being taken offline:

**.htaccess**

`php_value max_input_vars 4000`

**wp-config**

`@ini_set( 'max_input_vars' , 4000 );`

**Update:  09/01/2020**

I have also tried entering `php_admin_flag max_input_vars On` into the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file followed by entering `max_input_vars =4000` into the `/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/php.ini` file.

Unfortunately, the `max_input_vars =4000` still gets overridden with the default of 1000 being reset.  Furthermore, this approach produces the following notifications; within the server:

[image]

Could I be doing something wrong here?

Comment: You can't set `max_input_vars` using `ini_set`. To make it work in `.htaccess` you need to have specified `AllowOverride Options` or `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Where would I need to enter `AllowOverride Options` or `AllowOverride All`?

Answer (score 0):

So, [`max_input_vars`](https://www.php.net/info.configuration#ini.max-input-vars) is [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](https://www.php.net/configuration.changes.modes) which means it can be set in either php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (*since PHP 5.3*).

PHP only has one solution for preventing local directive overrides (*local directives override master directives in PHP so it bubbles from the bottom up*) and that's to set an [`admin_flag`](https://www.php.net/configuration.changes) on the directive, thus preventing the master configuration from being override locally. To do this it will depend on which PHP SAPI you're using.

### mod_php (Apache httpd)

You can set `php_admin_flag` in your apache config (i.e. virtualhost file or httpd.conf) using `php_admin_flag max_input_vars On` in your httpd config. This will prevent the loaded value from your php.ini to be overridden by .htaccess or `ini_set()`.

### php-fpm (fastcgi)

You can set the [`php_admin_flag`](https://www.php.net/install.fpm.configuration) in your php-fpm config or individual pool configs with the syntax `php_admin_flag[max_input_vars] = On`.

### N.B.

However, before proceeding please take under advisement the importance of not setting this directive too high as it can cause a known **Denial of Service** attack in PHP. From the manual...

> Use of this directive mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash collisions. If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an **E_WARNING** is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request.

Comment: Having run the `apachectl -V` command, it appears the Server Config File can be found at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.  Is this Ubuntu's variant of the `Apache httpd` file you mentioned in your answer?  If so, would I simply need to enter `php_admin_flag max_input_vars On` at the bottom of this `apache2.conf` file?  Does this file not get automatically updated?  How would this prevent the `max_input_vars =4000` entry from being overridden within the `php.ini` file that is located within the `/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/` directory?  Does it just stop the `php.ini` file being updated?

Comment: It doesn't stop php.ini from being updated. But it will prevent anything lower level than php.ini from overriding a php.ini. It goes like this in PHP (in order of loading configurations) 1. Hardcoded PHP defaults 2. php_admin_value config 3. php.ini 4. Runtime user-level php ini or .htaccess type config 5. runtime ini_set. So if you wanted to prevent even php.ini from changing it you could also set a `php_admin_value`. The `php_admin_flag` simply enforces that the loaded configuration cannot be overridden by runtime configuration directive like those found in .htaccess or ini_set().

Comment: Thank you for your continued support.  Unfortunately, your suggestion is triggering an error as well as resulting in the `max_input_vars =4000` still being overridden.  Could I be misunderstanding your guidance?  I have updated my question with the error message I am seeing.

Comment: You have to set it after mod_php is loaded

Comment: I have tried to get a better understanding of your answer but feel I am just confusing myself here.  You state `This will prevent the loaded value from your php.ini to be overridden by .htaccess`.  I assume this is the `.htaccess` within each websites' `httpdocs` folder?  If so, I cannot seem to change the `max_input_vars` within the `.htaccess` file plus I want to be able to override the `php.ini` file.  I just want to be able to change the `max_input_vars` without it being overridden.

Comment: Those are two contradicting things. I can't help you do both A and B since A directly conflicts with B, but I can help you do one or the other. To be able to override `php.ini` you simply have to do nothing. Leave everything the way it is. All local configurations already override master configurations. To do the exact opposite (*prevent people from overriding php.ini*) you have but to follow the very simple and straight-forward advice given in the answer above. Not sure how else I can possibly answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your time with the answer.  I have since learned that your suggestion  does not work for some sites that use WooCommerce; since WooCommerce is calling the `max_input_vars` from another source.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but my suggestions are universal in PHP.